# How to programmatically invoke an autocomplete dropdown?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to programmatically invoke the autocomplete dropdown using javascript in chrome devtools. Here is what I want to simulate programmatically (E.g. open chrome devtools while on google.com):

- click on the search box.
- autocomplete will dropdown with your previous search queries.

I tried to grab the HTML element using `document.getElementByClassName` and then call `dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown'))` then `dispatchEvent (new MouseEven('mouseup'))` with no luck. I also tried calling `click()` and `focus()` but that did not work either.

Comment: I assume you're talking about  the [autocomplete attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) and not any autocomplete library. Is this indeed the case?

Comment: I am talking about the one that gets invoked on mouse click. In case of google.com, it is dropdown menu that shows after clicking on the search box.